# What are the blanket or general terms representing these linguistic pitfalls?

Tags: terminology, etymology, philosophy-of-language

Are there collective, sweeping official terms that comprise linguistic traps such as these?

- [Etymological fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)
- Folk etymology
- False friend
- [False cognate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_cognate)
- [False etymology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_etymology)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a single term for these fallacies. But I agree that they are related and would benefit from an umbrella term to make it easier to point people to the profoundly problematic nature of these.

I would call them examples of **linguistic essentialism** - the belief (and often fervent faith and feeling) that there is something fundamental in the historical roots of language that we can access by uncovering the historical roots - or in other words, that words and expressions have a fundamental essence that always leaves a trace. It is a species of extreme philosophical realism. But as a trope, it is extremely popular with philosophers in the phenomenological tradition. Of course, it is a common ailment of the commentariat.

Another possible term could be **naive etymologism** since they are predicated on the myth of the primacy of the history of language. They are also related to prescriptivist and purist tendencies.